# How can I make email go to a local folder during testing?

Tags: asp.net, testing, smtp

How can I test sending email from my application without flooding my inbox?

Is there a way to tell IIS/ASP.NET how to deliver email to a local folder for inspection?

Comment: Don't close questions like this. Help the guy out instead.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes there is a way.

> You can alter web.config like this so
>   that when you send email it will
>   instead be created as an .EML file in
>   c:\LocalDir.

```
    <configuration>  
     <system.net>    
      <mailSettings>      
       <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">        
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\LocalDir"/>      
       </smtp>    
      </mailSettings>  
     </system.net>
    </configuration>
```

You can also create an instance of the [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class with these same settings, if you don't want to/can't change the web.config.  In C# that looks something like this:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
var emailPickupDirectory = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/EmailPickup");
if (!Directory.Exists(emailPickupDirectory)) { 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(emailPickupDirectory)
}
smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = emailPickupDirectory;
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure rules in your email client to move the messages based on the subject/sender's email address?