# Local Email Test on Vista Home

Tags: asp.net, windows-vista

What is the best way to test sending emails from a dev machine using Vista Home Basic?

Comment: As an update, I found the method described here to be the easiest way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177974/how-can-i-make-email-go-to-a-local-folder-during-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want source code (and thus have some more options for testing and logging) have a look at [Dumbster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dumbster/) (java) or the .NET port, [nDumbster](http://ndumbster.sourceforge.net/default.html). It won't (can't) relay.

Answer (score 1):

Free SMTP Server is free and works on Vista

http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html

Comment: Way down at the bottom of the list.
I've used this on Vista and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

unless you already have an SMTP server, then its just a case of creating a small test page to use the System.Net.Mail classes